# Having trouble with Hibernate HQL query containing nested aggregate functions

Tags: hibernate, hql

The following hql_query String works and delivers data records as expected. It gives me a list of lists, where the nested lists consist of a person pers and "the amount of persAccsBOs".

```
hql_query_string = ""
+ "select distinct pers, count(persAccsBOs) as anzBo from Person as pers"
+ " inner join pers.personenAttribute as persAttr inner join persAttr.pa_pk.attribut as pAttr"
+ " inner join pers.accounts as persAccs"
+ " inner join persAccs.berechtigungsobjekte as persAccsBOs"
+ " where pAttr.name='UID_Department'"
+ " and persAttr.wert='Sales (10100200)'"
+ " group by pers";
```

Now, what i want to achieve and fail with is to get the average value of all anzBo's. I tried the following query_string:

```
query_string = ""
+ "select avg(anzBo) from "
+ " (select distinct pers, count(persAccsBOs) as anzBo from Person as pers"
+ " inner join pers.personenAttribute as persAttr inner join persAttr.pa_pk.attribut as pAttr"
+ " inner join pers.accounts as persAccs"
+ " inner join persAccs.berechtigungsobjekte as persAccsBOs"
+ " where pAttr.name='UID_Department'"
+ " and persAttr.wert='Sales (10100200)'"
+ " group by pers)";
```

I get the error message:

> unexpected token: select near line 1, column 25 [select avg(anzBo)
>   from  select distinct pers ...

I hope you got the clue what im trying to do. Can you help me to form the correct hql_string?

UPDATE:

If i try this:

```
query_string = ""
+ "select distinct pers, count(persAccsBOs) as anzBo, avg(anzBo) from Person as pers"
+ " inner join pers.personenAttribute as persAttr inner join persAttr.pa_pk.attribut as pAttr"
+ " inner join pers.accounts as persAccs"
+ " inner join persAccs.berechtigungsobjekte as persAccsBOs"
+ " where pAttr.name='UID_Department'"
+ " and persAttr.wert='Sales (10100200)'"
+ " group by pers";
```

i will get a java.lang.NullPointerException.

Comment: I cannot suggest a way to do the nested select in HQL and I cannot be sure that this is your problem, though I suspect it might be. However, if you want the average of a value that appears in a list in Java, why not just calculate it directly from the values generated in the first query? It might be a little more CPU expensive, but it would solve your problem.

Comment: Have a look at my UPDATE. CPU costs do not matter. I just want to have it running.

Comment: Sorry, I think I'm missing the point here. If I understood your original assertion, then the initial query gives a list of value pairs. It should be possible to loop through the list and calculate the average. If I've really missed the point, you might have to show a bit more of your java code so I understand why that would not work. I'm leaving the office now, so I won't be able to answer again for around 2 - 3 hours... if you're willing to wait that long.

Comment: Hi Achim, the problem, im describing is apparently not solvable in hibernate:  // siehe: http://grails.1312388.n4.nabble.com/HQL-Nested-Aggregate-Functions-td4629813.html
 // http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14592975/hql-combining-aggregate-functions
 // http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17666843/average-of-subquery-in-gorm

Comment: That it isn't possible to do it in hibernate is pretty much what I expected. That's why I suggested doing it in the host language, which I assume is Java. I checked the 1st links and in both cases the suggested solution is to calculate the average manually. In the second case The comment from Johanna actually suggests that this might be faster than packing it into an SQL or HQL query. What ever you try, I wish you good luck.